# Number of solutions for (a-x)(b-y)-1=0

Tags: diophantine-equations

How to find number of integer solutions for x and y for given values of a and b .
is it related to number of divisors , i read it from a post bit didn't get it .
Anybody can explain with example .

Comment: You have this tagged as diophantine equations.  Are you restricting $x$ and $y$ to be integers?  If so, each parenthetical has to equal 1.

Comment: @tabstop yes integer solution

Answer (score 2):

The product $(a-x)(b-y)$ is $1$ iff $a-x=b-y=\pm1$, so you get two solutions.

Comment: and what if a=1 and b=-1 ?

Comment: then one of $x$ or $y$ would be zero.